# Стопориться на условии цикла

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Есть простой алгоритм, который должен считать произведение каждой чётной цифры 64 битного числа, которое может быть и отрицательным. Проблема в том, что он не работает, так как просто не входит в цикл, в отладке показывает, что дальше  while (numcount-G >= 0); не идёт, просто зависает на этом месте. numcount - целочисленная переменная, но почему-то не работает. Как это исправить ?
P.s: Не нужно предлогать решить с long long, сайт не полностью будет засчитывать решение, хоть всё правильно, наверное это из-за того, что если число негативное, то минус занимает место в памяти, что не даёт полностью записать само число.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main() {
   
    string n, o;
    int b;
    short G=0, numcount;
    long long multiplication = 1;
    cin >> n;
    o = n;
    if (o.erase(1, o.length()) == "-") G=1;
    numcount = n.length();
    while (numcount-G >= 0);
    {
        b = n[n.length() - 1];
        b = b + 2;
        b = b % 10; // b - последняя цифра числа. узнаётся по извращенски, но по другому не нашёл инфы как находить
       
       n.erase(n.length()-1, 1);
        if (b % 2 == 0 and b != 0) multiplication *= b;
        numcount = n.length();
    }
    cout << multiplication;
    
    }
```

Проблему решил, но вылезает ещё одна проблема
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уберите точку с запятой здесь: `while (numcount-G >= 0);`

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрел задание по ссылке. Ключевые моменты, на которых вы не акцентировали внимание в своём вопросе:

- 64-битное число, которое может быть и отрицательным — это число с диапазоном значений `[-(2**64 - 1); 2**64 - 1]`, а не `[-(2**63); 2**63 - 1]`, как можно было бы подумать на первый взгляд. Поэтому типа `long long` для хранения числа действительно может быть не достаточно.
- Цифра `0` считается чётной.
- Если входное число не содержит чётных цифр, то необходимо вывести `-1`.

Поэтому код будет такой:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string num;
    long long mult = 1;

    cin >> num;
    for (unsigned i = num[0] == '-'; i < num.size(); ++i)
    {
        char digit = num[i] - '0';
        if (digit % 2 == 0)
            mult *= digit;
    }
    if (mult == 1)
        mult = -1;
    cout << mult;
}
```

Comment: Это не правильно, не проходит 2 проверки. Поэтому нужно мудрить с string

Comment: Есть пример данных, на которых не проходит?

Comment: Сайт не предоставляет примеров данных проверки.

Comment: https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/problems/1604

Comment: @girub, обновил ответ.